# ArcGIS Calculate flooding area based on input amount of water

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arc-hydro, flood

I have created a DEM based on historical maps from 1816. I'm supposed to calculate the flooded area for certain amounts of water (in m³/s).

I intended to do it with ArcHydro - however, as far as I can see, ArcHydro takes the water gauge at certain points and based on this height it floods the area. The height is what I'm interested in though, to compare it with modern flooding data.

Since there exist no water gauge data for this date I'm at a loss on how to proceed. Is it possible with ArcHydro to set something like an input amount of water, or are there maybe different tools to solve this problem?

Comment: You have quite a lot to read. The amount of water is in flow units. ArcHydro does not perform hydraulic calculations. One tool could be HEC-RAS and its gis capabilities with RAS mapper. www.hec.usace.army.mil/software/hec-ras/